# How to create SQLiteDatabase and use it to populate spinner?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, spinner

I'm trying to make a unit conversion application and as of now I've made arrays of the unit areas within the string.xml-file like this:

```
    <string-array name="weight_name_array">
        <item>Gram</item>
        <item>Pound</item>
        <item>Ounce</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="weight_value_array">
        <item>1.0</item>
        <item>453.59237</item>
        <item>28.3495</item>
    </string-array>
```

I would like to replace this with a SQLiteDatabase consisting of two tables, `Weight` and `Length` but I'm very new to using SQLiteDB and I have tried to search for guidance, but can't seem to understand how to proceed.

What I'm trying to do is to have two columns in each table, `unitName` and `unitValue` and then I want the unitName to be displayed in a spinner. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're probably better off keeping it in the XML values.
There are not numbers that are changed..ever. 
A database is to keep storing changing or adding data, not really for static data that never changes anyway.

That aside, there are tons of proper tutorials on how to use the SQLite database in Android, as it is a basic and core feature.

Try [Vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html) and just google whatever you do not find on there.

Comment: The thing is that I want the user to be able to add new measurement areas and new units, so that's why I was thinking of the DB. Could this be done any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this on Youtube to get a basic better understanding : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUoGnvz_Yw4 and also other available tutorials at Youtube. Along with it, you can watch out - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html as well.

I've used SQLiteDatabase in one of my requirements as part of the tutorials. It has creation of the table, inserting as well as upgrade methods for your reference. I believe it will help you

StatusData.Java

```
import winterwell.jtwitter.Status;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class StatusData {
    static final String TAG = "StatusData";
    public static final String DB_NAME = "timeline.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE = "status";
    public static final String C_ID = "_id";
    public static final String C_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    public static final String C_USER = "user_name";
    public static final String C_TEXT = "status_text";

    Context context;
    DbHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public StatusData(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        dbHelper = new DbHelper();
    }

    public void insert(Status status) {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(C_ID, status.id.toString());
        values.put(C_CREATED_AT, status.createdAt.getTime());
        values.put(C_USER, status.user.name);
        values.put(C_TEXT, status.text);
        db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
        db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE, null, values,
                SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
    }

    class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper() {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String sql = String.format("Create Table : %s "
                    + "(%s int Primary Key,  " + "%s int, %s text, %s text)",
                    TABLE, C_ID, C_CREATED_AT, C_USER, C_TEXT);
            Log.d(TAG, "Oncreate with SQL : " + sql);
            db.execSQL(sql);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // Usually ALTER the TABLE
            db.execSQL("drop if exists  " + TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }
```